# How to catch GMail auto-refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, gmail, greasemonkey

I wrote a [userscript](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/71392) to highlight the current row in GMail (indicated by the arrow). Unfortunately the highlight will only stay until GMail Inbox is auto-refreshed, which happens quite often. Is there a way to catch that event so I could reapply the highlighting? I don't want to do it on timeout. There is another userscript that does that and it loads up CPU.

Comment: It was suggested elsewhere to use DOMNodeInserted, but I understand it will only fire up when there is a new message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like you will want to review [this document which is documentation for the Gmail gmonkey API](https://code.google.com/p/gmail-greasemonkey/wiki/GmailGreasemonkey10API), which is an API that google provides for greasemonkey scripts.

[This page describes a userscript which monitors view changes](https://code.google.com/p/gmail-greasemonkey/wiki/ArticleGmailViewWatcher), and this should be very similar to what you need.

I assume you will want something like:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  if (unsafeWindow.gmonkey) {
    unsafeWindow.gmonkey.load('1.0', function(gmail) {
      function changedViewType() {
        // Threadlist
        if(gmail.getActiveViewType()== "tl"){
          // code to highlight the current row here...
        }
      }
      gmail.registerViewChangeCallback(changedViewType);
      changedViewType();
    });
  }
}, true);
```

Comment: I finally got around to checking this and it doesn't work. Neither does the sample script on that page, Gmail View Watcher.

Comment: Gmail Greasemonkey API abandoned? See http://code.google.com/p/gmail-greasemonkey/issues/detail?id=39

Answer (score 1):

If you add a timer and look when your highlight element disappear? or if a parent object change its address (with ===).

Comment: Yep, that's what I said I DON'T want to do - use timer. Try it, you'll see CPU usage hovering just under 50%.

Answer (score 0):

consider a CSS userstyle (http://userstyles.org/ ) instead of a userscript. You can use Firefox's DOM inspector to look at the HTMl elements and classes in the selected row, and then it should be pretty straightforward to write a CSS selector that select just that row.

Comment: ryan, the question is how to catch an event. I have no problem selecting a row.

Answer (score 0):

The following code does work with the current gmail UI as of today, credits go to https://cleverinsert.com/ taken from their [gmail plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gmail-show-time/jgjaapljoafhkohbnfigoekjgdfddnnn/related). The callback is fired everytime the inbox is refreshed. You have to create the MutationSummary after the document has loaded completely. You can install and debug their plugin in chrome to check it out.

You have to include the [mutation-summary.js](https://github.com/rafaelw/mutation-summary)

```
new MutationSummary({
  callback: render,
  rootNode: document.querySelector('.AO'),
  observeOwnChanges: false,
  oldPreviousSibling: true,
  queries: [
      { element: 'td.xW' }
  ]});

function render(a) {
  console.log("callback triggered");           
}
```